# ESLint: Getting the error "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, recoiljs

I am currently making a TodoList app using Recoil and React and I am getting the error:

```
 Line 45:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'setTodoList' and 'todoList'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

I believe this is preventing the app from building. It works in development mode.

Please help me fix this!

Here is the concerned file:

```
export default function Todos() {
  // Global State Hooks
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useRecoilState(todoState);
  const changing = useRevoilValue(changeState);
  const show = useRecoilValue(addState);
  const removing = useRecoilValue(removeState);
  const priority = useRecoilValue(priorityState);

  // **** CODE SEGMENT STARTS HERE ****

  useEffect(() => {
    if (priority) {
      setTodoList(
        todoList.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.priority - b.priority; // By priority
        })
      );
    } else {
      setTodoList(
        todoList.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.title.localeCompare(b.title); // By name
        })
      );
    }
    // Watches priority for sortButton, and editing, adding and deleting modes etc.
  }, [priority, changing, show, removing]);

  // **** CODE SEGMENT ENDS HERE ****

  return (
    <div className={styles.todos}>
      {/* Dynamically render  todo items */}
      {todoList.map((todo, index) => (
        <span key={todo.id} className={styles.todoItem}>
          <TodoItem key={index} item={todo} />
        </span>
      ))}
      {/* Todo Form only appears in adding mode */}
      {show ? <TodoForm /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a warning that React gives back. By this React wants us to use the `setTodoList` and `todoList` are the dependencies in the array of the 2nd argument.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (priority) {
      setTodoList(
        todoList.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.priority - b.priority; // By priority
        })
      );
    } else {
      setTodoList(
        todoList.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.title.localeCompare(b.title); // By name
        })
      );
    }
    // Watches priority for sortButton, and editing, adding and deleting modes etc.
  }, [priority, changing, show, removing,todoList,setTodoList]); // Added todoList and setTodoList as dependencies
```

However we have to be cautious of not creating an `infinite loop` in our Component. Because `setTodoList()` will trigger a re-render of the component and again `useEffect()` will be invoked. This will keep happening.

And if this happens The solution is to use `useCallback()` around `setTodoList` to prevent re-creation of the function every time (We may need to format our code a bit as well)

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by your eslint rules: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html
You can turn off the rule in your `eslint.rc` by adding:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the error could cause a number of preventable bugs.